# ASP MVC EF MultiSelect HTTP POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**My Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(BlogCompModel blogmodel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

**My View:**

```
@model BlogProject.Models.BlogCompModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    ...


   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogCompModel.posts, "Property", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.posts, new MultiSelectList(Model.posts, "post_ID", "postTitle"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.posts.posts)
      </div>
   </div>

}
```

**Error message on post:**

```
"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'BlogProject.Models.Posts' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}  System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

As you can see, I'm not sure how to translate the HTML Multiselect list from a collection of Post_IDs to an ICollection of posts.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't deal much with MVC, but here is a link that may help you (http://forums.asp.net/t/1778536.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another property in your `BlogCompModel` Model, it'll wrap all selected post in it.

```
public class BlogCompModel
{
    // 
    public string[] selectedPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selectedPosts , 
                 new MultiSelectList(Model.posts, "post_ID", "postTitle"))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedPosts )
```

Comment: Is it possible to bind the return type from the view to a type in my model (ICollection)?  Or do I need to iterate over the primitive type of my controller and populate the ICollection?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I don't know what your `BlogCompModel` model looks like, but from the code you provided you just need add a field . If you want to know more about bind a list to model, take a look at the following link:http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

In my blog MVC app, I've a multiselect for Tags and here how I add those to Post in Create action.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model MyBlog.Core.Post

 @Html.ListBox("PostTags", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.MultiSelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**controller**

```
public ActionResult CreatePost([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,ShortDescription,Description,Published,PostedOn,ModifiedOn,CategoryId")] Post post, int[] postTags)
        {
            if (postTags != null)
            {
                foreach (var t in postTags)
                {
                    var tag = _dbTag.GetById(t);
                    post.Tags.Add(tag);
                }
            }
           // save to database and other stuff
           return View(post);
        }
```